# The premium item on the Re-Tail sign reset?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My Re-Tail sign had two items available for premium sale, and out of nowhere the sign reset to one item! Has this happened to anyone else? Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Where you playing at night?

Comment: Was it all of a sudden, in the middle of the day, or was it from one day to the next?

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your ordinance then it will change the number of premium items. The Bell Boom ordinance gives you two items. The others only give one.